# jquery targeting val from a selected options and then showing a corresponding div

Tags: jquery, css, select, html

Hi i am trying to show the corresponding div when you choose in the selection and then showing the correct div. example a choose the plane in the selection then showing the div that says you have chosen a plane and so on.

CSS

```
#car{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#plane{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#boat{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

options:<select id='selection'>
    <option val='1' id='1'>Car</option>
    <option val='2' id='2'>Plane</option>
    <option val='3' id='3'>Boat</option>
</select>

<div id='car'>you have chosen a car</div>
<div id='plane'>you have chosen a plane</div>
<div id='boat'>you have chosen a boat</div>


</body>
```

Any help would really be appreciated and thanks!

Comment: thanks to everyone that helped it seems that mplungjan helped with the mistery because of the css that hide the div the js was working fine also everyone else's codes were working the problem was i didn't adjust for the css that makes the visibility hidden so it stayed hidden but still thanks for everyones help in solving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[<kbd>***Live Demo***</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QLurU/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#selection").on("change", function() {
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
    if (id) $("#"+id).show().siblings("div").hide();
  }).trigger("change"); // initialise on load
});
```

To not be dependant on the text in the select, you can change

```
    var id = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
```

to have the IDs of the divs in an array - that does mean possible duplication but it moves all the dependencies to the script.

```
    var id = ["car","plane","boat"][this.selectedIndex];
```

or if you have an empty first option:

```
    var id = ["","car","plane","boat"][this.selectedIndex];
```

---

Full code since it seems you have issues with the jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test selections</title>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("#selection").on("change", function() {
          var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
          if (text) $("#"+text).show().siblings("div").hide();
        }).trigger("change");
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      options:<select id='selection'>
        <option value='1'>Car</option>
        <option value='2'>Plane</option>
        <option value='3'>Boat</option>
      </select>

      <div id='car'>you have chosen a car</div>
      <div id='plane'>you have chosen a plane</div>
      <div id='boat'>you have chosen a boat</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What if he puts an option with a space in it?

Comment: @mattytommo - if you downvoted, please review. If not, whoever did, please comment

Comment: thanks for helping but it also seems that i works for you but it doesn't work for me T_T i have to put it between  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> but it still doesnt show any i dont have any idea why

Comment: thanks for helping i saw the demo to but still to no avail T_T also i downloaded the js and still nothing any suggestiong?

Comment: thanks i re tried is and it work! it seems that the part that was messing with showing the results was the css so i will try and add more code to adjust for the css but still thanks very much!

Comment: My code does not need CSS. The trigger will hide the ones not selected onload too

Comment: yea i saw that the one i needed to fix was mine that it still hade the css so it didnt show and when i tried your and reviewed the codes the problem was the css and that solve it thanks again!

Comment: @mplungjan a +1 for you

Answer (score 3):

You're best off giving your options `data` attributes to hold the corresponding div ID. Something like:

```
<select id='selection'>
    <option val='1' id='1' data-div="car">Car</option>
    <option val='2' id='2' data-div="plane">Plane</option>
    <option val='3' id='3' data-div="boat">Boat</option>
</select>
```

Then in jQuery you can do:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selection").change(function () {
        var divItem = $(this).children("option:selected").data("div");
        $("div:not(#" + divItem + ")").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#" + divItem).css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JuEFe/)

Comment: how come it doesnt show anything for me but when i try your demo it works fine? T_T sorry im really new at this

Comment: @user1868185 Have you definitely added those data attributes for each option?

Comment: No need for data if the IDs match the text. See my suggestion

Comment: @mplungjan What happens if he puts Roller Skates or something else with a space in the text? That solution would break.

Comment: Then he would use your suggestion or add a replace to mine. Right now, the text matches the divs and there is a one to one relationship

Comment: thanks for helping but mine still doesn't work also tried downloading the js and using it rather than in the web but still nothing and i also saw the demo good stuff to but mine doesnt work any idea why and thanks!

Comment: @user1868185 Are there any errors in the dev tools of your browser?

Comment: @user1868185 Nah you'll have to press F12 and go to the Console window.

Comment: thanks for helping it seems that adjusting the css and then trying to show it when click then showing the div fixes it still thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TB5BW/1/)**

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#' + $('#selection option:selected').text().toLowerCase()).show();
    $('#selection').change(function () {
        $('.op').hide();
        $('#' + $('#selection option:selected').text().toLowerCase()).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan check the demo and then down vote. $('#selection').val() means value of the selcet, not option val()

Comment: The code I am looking at is using the .val().toLowerCase() which 
ONLY works because the OP has used `val=`. if he fixes that, your code will fail. 
The values of the select is 1,2,3 and not car,plane,boat.

Comment: thanks for helping it seems i needed to adjust the css to show the div thats why it didnt work for me but still thanks!

Comment: Now you fixed it. +1 - I would like one from you too since I was voted down twice by hit and run downvoters

Comment: I never thought you did

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. First.. Your `<option val="">` is incorrect, change it to `<option value="">`

There is a couple of answers that can do what you want, here is one and very simple:

[Example JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OvaDinE/2/edit)

HTML:

```
<body>

options: 

  <select id="selection">
     <option value="0">Select</option>
     <option value="1">Car</option>
     <option value="2">Plane</option>
     <option value="3">Boat</option>  
  </select>

<div id='car'>you have chosen a car</div>
<div id='plane'>you have chosen a plane</div>
<div id='boat'>you have chosen a boat</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#car, #plane, #boat {

    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

   $("#selection").on("change", function(){

      if ($(this).val() == 0) {

          $("#car, #plane, #boat").hide();

      } else if ($(this).val() == 1) {

          $("#plane, #boat").hide();

          $("#car").fadeIn();

      } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {

          $("#car, #boat").hide();

          $("#plane").fadeIn();

      } else {

          $("#car, #plane").hide();

          $("#boat").fadeIn();
      }  
  });
});
```

Comment: it works in the cloud but it doesnt seem to work in my localhost also tried the simple stuff like clicking buttons and h1 and hiding them and it works but the select doesnt seem to work for me but still thanks!

Comment: thanks for the help it seems that i needed to adjust the css that hides it into showing it again but still thanks!